# FFMPEG not found because FFMPEG-binaries is no longer supported

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord

I have been attempting to create a Discord bot, but it cannot connect to a voice channel because it gives the error`Error: FFMPEG not found`. Is there a way to get around using FFMPEG-binaries or an older version that I can install manually?

```html
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {
 prefix,
 token,
} = require('./config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
 console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
 console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
 if (message.author.bot) return;
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

 const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

 if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
  execute(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
  skip(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
  stop(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else {
  message.channel.send('You need to enter a valid command!')
 }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
 const args = message.content.split(' ');

 const voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
 if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
 const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
 if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
  return message.channel.send('I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!');
 }

 const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
 const song = {
  title: songInfo.title,
  url: songInfo.video_url,
 };

 if (!serverQueue) {
  const queueContruct = {
   textChannel: message.channel,
   voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
   connection: null,
   songs: [],
   volume: 5,
   playing: true,
  };

  queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

  queueContruct.songs.push(song);

  try {
   var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
   queueContruct.connection = connection;
   play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   queue.delete(message.guild.id);
   return message.channel.send(err);
  }
 } else {
  serverQueue.songs.push(song);
  console.log(serverQueue.songs);
  return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
 }

}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
 if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
 if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send('There is no song that I could skip!');
 serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
 if (!message.member.voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!');
 serverQueue.songs = [];
 serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
 const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);

 if (!song) {
  serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
  queue.delete(guild.id);
  return;
 }

 const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection.playStream(ytdl(song.url))
  .on('end', () => {
   console.log('Music ended!');
   serverQueue.songs.shift();
   play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
  })
  .on('error', error => {
   console.error(error);
  });
 dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
}

client.login(token);
```

This is the error that appears after I attempt to '!play '.

```html
D:\Bot-Files-Test>node index.js
Ready!
Error: FFMPEG not found
    at Function.selectFfmpegCommand (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:46:13)
    at new FfmpegTranscoder (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\ffmpeg\Ffmpeg.js:7:37)
    at new MediaTranscoder (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\prism-media\src\transcoders\MediaTranscoder.js:10:19)
    at new Prism (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\prism-media\src\Prism.js:5:23)
    at new VoiceConnection (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\VoiceConnection.js:46:18)
    at D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js:63:22
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at ClientVoiceManager.joinChannel (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\ClientVoiceManager.js:45:12)
    at VoiceChannel.join (D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\VoiceChannel.js:130:30)
    at execute (D:\Bot-Files-Test\index.js:75:40)
(node:9108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
    at D:\Bot-Files-Test\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:9108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:9108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: perhaps you need to install ffmpeg on your system 
Download the correct version from here: https://ffbinaries.com/downloads

Comment: @Sylens I was able to download and place the exe's in the directory that the bot is working from, but now it's throwing a separate error, 'DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message'